# MVC 3 client caching

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, caching

I am trying to make modifications to an existing CDN. What I am trying to do is create a short cache time and use conditional GETs to see if the file has been updated.

I am tearing my hair out because even though I am setting a last modified date and seeing it in the response headers, on subsequent get requests I am not seeing an If-Modified-Since header being returned. At first I thought it  was my local development environment or the fact that I was using Fiddler as a proxy for testing so I deployed to a QA server. But what I am seeing in Firebug is so different than what I am doing. I see the last modified date, for some reason it is setting my cache-control to private, and I have cleared any header Output Caching and the only header IIS 7.5 is set to write is to enable Http keep-alive, so all the caching should be driven by the code.

This seemed like such a no-brainer, yet I've been adding and removing headers all day with no luck. I checked global.asax and anywhere else (I didn't write the app so I was looking for any hidden surprises and am stumped. Below is the current code and request and response headers. I have the expiration set to 30 seconds just for testing purposes. I have looked at several samples, I don't see myself doing anything different, but it simply won't work.

```
Response Headersview source
Cache-Control   private, max-age=30
Content-Length  597353
Content-Type    image/jpg
Date    Tue, 03 Sep 2013 21:33:55 GMT
Expires Tue, 03 Sep 2013 21:34:25 GMT
Last-Modified   Tue, 03 Sep 2013 21:33:55 GMT
Server  Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version    4.0.30319
X-AspNetMvc-Version 3.0
X-Powered-By    ASP.NET
Request Headersview source
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
Connection  keep-alive
Cookie  __utma=1.759556114.1354835397.1377631052.1377732484.36; __utmz=1.1354835397.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)
Host    hqat4app1
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0
```

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
Response.Cache.SetLastModified(DateTime.Now);

return new FileContentResult(fileContents, contentType);
```

The relevant code is:

```
public ActionResult Resize(int id, int size, bool grayscale)
{
    _logger.Debug(() => string.Format("Resize {0} {1} {2}", id, size, grayscale));

    string imageFileName = null;

    if (id > 0)
        using (new UnitOfWorkScope())
            imageFileName = RepositoryFactory.CreateReadOnly<Image>().Where(o => o.Id == id).Select(o => o.FileName).SingleOrDefault();

    CacheImageSize(id, size);

    if (!ImageWasModified(imageFileName))
    {
        Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(30));
        Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.NotModified;
        Response.Status = "304 Not Modified";
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult((int)HttpStatusCode.NotModified, "Not-Modified");
    }

    byte[] fileContents;
    if (ShouldReturnDefaultImage(imageFileName))
        fileContents = GetDefaultImageContents(size, grayscale);
    else
    {
        bool foundImageFile;
        fileContents = GetImageContents(id, size, grayscale, imageFileName, out foundImageFile);

        if (!foundImageFile)
        {
            // No file found, clear cache, disable output cache
            //ClearOutputAndRuntimeCacheForImage(id, grayscale);
            //Response.DisableKernelCache();
        }
    }
    string contentType = GetBestContentType(imageFileName);

    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
    Response.Cache.SetLastModified(DateTime.Now);

    return new FileContentResult(fileContents, contentType);
}

private bool ImageWasModified(string fileName)
{
    bool foundImageFile;

    string filePath = GetFileOrDefaultPath(fileName, out foundImageFile);

    if (foundImageFile)
    {
        string header = Request.Headers["If-Modified-Since"];

        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(header))
        {
            DateTime isModifiedSince;
            if (DateTime.TryParse(header, out isModifiedSince))
            {
                return isModifiedSince < System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(filePath);
            }

        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Found my answer, finally and I feel like an idiot. I was setting the expires tag on the cache. Instead I used the addHeader method the response object and suddenly I was getting my 304's.

Comment: Err, I should say last modified. It's been a long day. Response.Cache.SetLastModified(DateTime.Now); was wrong.